# How to retrieve the date child from firebase android

Tags: android, firebase, date, firebase-realtime-database

In this
[firebase console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mN8Az.jpg), You can see the `Users` having the `currentuserid` child in that it also contains the child `date` and `Name`.

I need to retrieve that `date` followed by that `date` child.
I have also included the code I tried. Thanks in advance.

```
Firebase auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
        dbuser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");
    }

    dbuser.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
          String view = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).getValue());
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), view, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: To avoid ambiguous in your database, always get your date as like this `new Date().getTime()`

Comment: So what you want to get, the date object or the data as a String? Or the children under the date?

Comment: @AlexMamo I want that date object to get the children details under that.

Comment: @Ineedajob In that case, I will get the informations on that date only. I want to get previous one's.

Answer (score 0):

Make a reference to the data and use

```
String dateKey =FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(currentuserid).child(date);
String date =  dateKey.getKey();
```

Then use `dataSnapshot` to get the date children.

Comment: Thanks for ur answer. But I'm not sure about the date they entered. I want to get the date child details.